# Not able to convert decimal numbers into SqlDecimal

Tags: c#

I've got a decimal number for example: -80.63 stored in a field "myvalue". Whenever I'm trying to convert it into a sqldecimal I get the following error:

***Cannot unbox 'myvalue' as a 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal'    ***

The code is as this:

```
String MyString = ((SqlDecimal)myvalue).Value.ToString("N");
```

As I understand decimal it should not be a precision error (it also happens with positive numbers btw). So my question here is: What causes this error?

As it was asked about in a comment: myvalue is part of a datatable (as example DataTable mytable with what is in myvalue being one of the columns values):

```
foreach (DataRow detail in myDataTable)
{
    var myvalue = detail["Sum"];
    String MyString = ((SqlDecimal)myvalue).Value.ToString("N");
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your objective??

Comment: And what is the type of `myvalue`? It would really help if you'd give us some context. (It's also unclear why you're converting it to a string, too...)

Comment: If `myvalue` is a `decimal`, why do you want to cast it to a `SqlDecimal`? What is wrong with `myvalue.ToString("N")`? If it's not a `decimal` tell us what it is.

Comment: I'm currently modifying code that was not created by myself (the above line an example of that. In total I got data from an sql database that uses up to the full decimal places available via sql. I just need to have the data transformed into a string to be written into a file (MyString is directly written as a string into a file)

Comment: @TimSchmelter for the type of myvalue: All I see is "object" thanks to the data from the sql being loaded into a datatable. will mention that in the question.

Comment: @Thomas: how do you initialize `myvalue`? If it's a field in a `DataRow` use `decimal d = row.Field<decimal>("ColumnName");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I see is "object" thanks to the data from the sql being loaded
>   into a datatable.

Then use the [`DataRow.Field` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.90).aspx) to get the `decimal` value.

For example:

```
foreach (DataRow detail in myDataTable)
{
    decimal myvalue = detail.Field<decimal>("Sum");
    string valueToDisplay = myvalue.ToString("N");
}
```

Note that it even supports nullables, so if the column can contain `NULL`s:

```
foreach (DataRow detail in myDataTable)
{
    decimal? myvalue = detail.Field<decimal?>("Sum");
    string valueToDisplay = myvalue.HasValue ? myvalue.Value.ToString("N") : "";
}
```

Comment: Works quite well tnx. will keep in mind that I can use the field value there (can only accept the answer in 4 mins according to SO)